# WPF ListBox selection index strange behavior after change order of connected items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

In short, how to swap two neighbour elements of [ListBox.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items.aspx)?

Details follow.

I use WPF ListBox.
(I use MVVM patern - no so important for this queston, just for clarity)

I define ListBox with following XAML definition:

```
    <ListBox Name="listBox1" 
             DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding StringList}"
             SelectedIndex="{Binding StringListSelectedItem}" />
```

View-model code fragment follows:

```
    public ObservableCollection<StringWrapper> StringList {get; set;}

    private int stringListSelectedItem;

    public int StringListSelectedItem
    {
        get {return stringListSelectedItem;}
        set {
            stringListSelectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StringListSelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

`StringWrapper` is just a small class to avoid [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176575/selection-bug-for-listbox-where-the-list-items-are-value-types-structs-and-con) with the same string values in the list box:

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public StringWrapper(string v)
    {
        Value = v;
    }
}
```

I want to swap order of two elements of the list:

```
        StringWrapper tmp = StringList[index];
        StringList[index] = StringList[index - 1];
        StringList[index - 1] = tmp;
```

After executing such swap, I obtain incorrect behaviour when assign values to `StringListSelectedItem`: several items in UI are selected,
but `listBox1.SelectionMode == Single`.
Moreover it seems when I check variables values in debugger, all looks fine, but in window when I run the application I see several selected items in `ListBox`.

It can be fixed by executing following code after swap:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < vm.StringList.Count(); i++) 
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
```

but it is not good idea every time to traverse all items, when I need just to set selected item.

What is wrong with my code? Does it corrupt something? How to obtain correct behavior of `SelectedIndex`?
Thanks.

Comment: Its almost always better to go with `SelectedItem` rather than deal with the index.

Comment: How to swap two items without indices?

Comment: Instance comparison.  Its UI work, you don't have to worry about performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this:

```
    StringWrapper tmp = StringList[index];
    StringList[index] = StringList[index - 1];
    StringList[index - 1] = tmp;
```

try this:

```
    StringWrapper tmp = StringList[index];
    StringList.RemoveAt(index);
    StringList.Insert(index-1,tmp);
```

Comment: It is much better, than my workaround. Anyway I don't understand why my code does not work.

Comment: I'd assume there is some mess going on accessing these items through indexers. Especially by setting `StringList[index] = StringList[index - 1];` you have that specific item twice in the list! So remember: altering an observablecollection is done through adding/removing/clearing

Comment: I tried the code with creating new `StringWrappper`s on assignments - it did not resolve the issue as well despite all objects were different. Anyway good rule is to use add/remove/clear and avoid `[]`-pitfall from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The code you supplied the selection mode is not set to single. Are you sure that in your app you have that set correctly? If so are you setting the selection mode in code behind or actually in the XAML? If it's in the code behind I suspect the databinding/selecting items is happening at startup before code behind setting the selection mode runs. To be safe set the selection mode in the xaml along with the bindings.

Also try using Binding Path not Binding something like:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" 
             DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding StringList}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=StringListSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
             SelectionMode="Single"/>
```

Comment: I had not setup selection single mode explictly, it seems it is defualt - I rechecked in in debugger. I tried also your code, result the same - buggy appearence when assign StringListSelectedItem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a small extension for the built-in ObservableCollection that ensures that when a item of the collection changes all other items get notified as well.

Use this subclass:

```
public class ExtednedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> {

    public ExtednedObservableCollection()
        : base() {

        this.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnCollectionChanged);
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {


        if (e.NewItems != null) {

            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems) {

                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null) {

            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems) {

                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs a = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        OnCollectionChanged(a);
    }

}
```