# ListBox.SelectedItems Get Index If Same Text

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Have a listbox of employees an employee can appear twice as an employee can have multiple attributes.

```
 List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            foreach (var item in employeeListBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                employees.Add(company.getEmployees()[employeeListBox.Items.IndexOf(item)]);
            }
```

Code above is being used at the moment but if the same employee with same name shows up twice only the first instance of the employee would be added to list.

If I try to add both instances only the first instance is added but two times.

**Besides changing the text within the listbox** is there another way I can get the index of the employee?

```
  public void addEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            if (employees == null)
                employees = new List<Employee>();
            employees.Add(emp);
        }

        public void removeEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            employees.Remove(emp); 
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployees()
        {
            return this.employees; 
        }

 company = Company.Load(Utilities.ComanySerialized);
                if (company.getEmployees() != null)
                    foreach (Employee b in company.getEmployees())
                    {
                        employeeListBox.Items.Add(b.getLastName() + " " + b.getFirstName() + "; " + b.getDateOfBirth());
                    }
```

Comment: please show the code for getEmployees()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure the best way without changing the text is to create a logic loop so that repeated indexes will be recorded and compared... Complicated stuff

Best way for normal use is just to name it different.

Answer (score 0):

If the instances are identical, then what's the issue with having it added twice? Regardless, see this answer ([Selection bug for listbox where the list items are value types / structs and contain duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176575/selection-bug-for-listbox-where-the-list-items-are-value-types-structs-and-con)) for a potential workaround.

Essentially, ListBox in WPF doesn't seem to have a way to get all the selected indeces, so if you select two identical objects, you'll only get the selection index of the first instance in the list. The solution then is to wrap your Employees into wrappers with some unique id.

Comment: They aren't identical, same employee on list 2 times with different attributes. But I guess I can't exactly keep things the way they are.

Comment: From the point of view of the ListBox you are adding a string.  You could create a new property in employee that returns the string that you're looking for b.getLastName() + " " + b.getFirstName() + "; " + b.getDateOfBirth(), but pass the entire Employee object to the listbox.  Something like "<ListBox x:Name="customListBox" DisplayMemberPath="MyDisplayName" , where Employee.MyDisplayName just returns the concatenation you have above. Then so long as you have two different Employee objects, it should return the correct index.